# getting null value in span element

Tags: javascript, html, json, api, console.log

When i try to run my index.html file

```
<div class="quote-text">
        <i class="fas fa-quote-left"></i>
        <span id="quote"></span>
    </div>
    <!-- author element -->
    <div class="quote-author">
        <span id="author"></span>
    </div>
```

my textContent method is not showing anything.

```
const quoteText = document.getElementById("quote");
const authorText = document.getElementById("author");

let apiQuotes = [] 

function newQuote(){
    const ranQuote = apiQuotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * apiQuotes.length)];
    console.log(ranQuote);
    console.log(ranQuote.text);
    console.log(ranQuote.author);
    console.log(quoteText);<!-- this shows null -->
    console.log(authorText); <!-- this shows null -->
    quoteText.textContent = ranQuote.text;
    authorText.textContent = ranQuote.author;
};

async function getQuotes(){
    const apiUrl = 'https://type.fit/api/quotes';
    try{
        const response = await fetch(apiUrl);
        apiQuotes = await response.json()
        newQuote();
    }
    catch(error){
    }
}

getQuotes();
```

I console logged span element value and its logging null. And i can't change my desired value in span element

[this is console screeenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EjHFS.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working as expected, as you can see in the snippet below.
Make sure you are running this script **after** DOM elements are created.
Put your script just before `</body>`, or make sure it executes after [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) (Stack snippet below does this ^)

```js
const quoteText = document.getElementById("quote");
const authorText = document.getElementById("author");

let apiQuotes = []

function newQuote() {
  const ranQuote = apiQuotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * apiQuotes.length)];
  console.log(ranQuote);
  console.log(ranQuote.text);
  console.log(ranQuote.author);
  console.log(quoteText); <!-- this shows null -->
  console.log(authorText); <!-- this shows null -->
  quoteText.textContent = ranQuote.text;
  authorText.textContent = ranQuote.author;
};

async function getQuotes() {
  const apiUrl = 'https://type.fit/api/quotes';
  try {
    const response = await fetch(apiUrl);
    apiQuotes = await response.json()
    newQuote();
  } catch (error) {}
}

getQuotes();
```

```html
<div class="quote-text">
  <i class="fas fa-quote-left"></i>
  <span id="quote">Wait for the request to finish...</span>
</div>
<!-- author element -->
<div class="quote-author">
  <span id="author"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Just saw my script was running before the body. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Oh got it sir. I am kinda new here so don't know much about it. Marked yours!